PHP7.4 headers for CSV download
relative newbie here, so please be gentle!
I'm trying to write a file to the browser for download and I have the following headers:
// Create a file pointer connected to the file path
$output = fopen($file_path, 'w');
if ($output === false) {
    die("Unable to open file for writing: " . $file_path);
}

// Output the column headings if there are any results
if (count($data) > 0) {
    fputcsv($output, array_keys($data[0]));
}

// Output the data
foreach ($data as $row) {
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}

// Close the file pointer
fclose($output);

// Close the database connection
$mysqli->close();

// Clear the output buffer
while (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}

if (file_exists($file_path)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file_path) . '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));
    readfile($file_path);
}

Yes, the file does exist (I've verified that) and I've tried Content-Type: application/csv and Content-Type: text/csv but that doesn't work either, the contents of the file are written to the browser, rather than served for download. Can anyone help me?

My first guess is that something else is being written to the stream first, thus negating your header function calls. Do you have full error reporting enabled?

You've shown us your code, but haven't actually said what happens / doesn't happen. You say "that doesn't work either", but what does that mean exactly? Do you get an error? A blank page? Content in the browser window instead of a download? Click [edit] and be as specific as you can.

thanks @ChrisHaas I have added the code prior to the headers, which includes clearing the stream.

Thanks @IMSoP the program runs and the output is written to the file, but when I ask it to serve as download, it writes the output CSV to the browser screen

Is there a reason why you need to clear the output buffer in the first place? Also, it might be worth checking headers_sent()

Interesting one, but worth posting in case anyone else is struggling. I had a couple of 'echo' statements, for debugging purposes, after the 'write to file' and before the 'serve for download' sections, which appartently cause issues with the output stream. Removing all debugging interferences made the code work! Thank you to everyone for your useful suggestions.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
